# Can't test element which is styled to display: none

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, styled-components, react-testing-library

I am trying to `getByRole` where I have an `<li />`, which is a child of a styled component.

The styled component is by default `display: none`, then under a `min-width` media query it's set to `display: flex`.

Running `getByRole('listitem')` works without the `display: none` but not with it, indicating that `styled-components` is telling the DOM that because it is set to `display: none` it doesn't exist.

This is despite the debug HTML output actually showing the `<li />` being rendered:

```
TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find an accessible element with the role "listitem"

    Here are the accessible roles:

      document:

      Name "":
      <body />

      --------------------------------------------------

    <body>
      <div>
        <div>
          <ul
              class="sc-gzVnrw sc-VigVT kjwzNy"
            >
              <li><!-- bunch of stuff --></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </body>
```

I have tried mocking the media query matching using `jest-matchmedia-mock`, with no luck.

I don't care about testing the media query or styles at all, so is there a way I can tell styled components to not apply the styles during testing?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I found a kind of solution which is a feature of dom-testing-library:

```js
getByRole('listitem', { hidden: true })
```

This includes hidden items.

There is a commit detailing this change here: https://github.com/testing-library/dom-testing-library/pull/352/files/7cdfcfa466774ca78940330fe95d00c9e744b673